# Getting non-tree ancestry graph for latex from gramps

Tags: gramps

See the project here https://github.com/gramps-project/gramps

There is an addon that does a nice export for trees https://ctan.org/pkg/genealogytree but it only does trees and not the whole database (or a filtered subset).

And you can export various default formats using graphviz to png or pdf but the layout is a bit strange. Obviously you can customize layout and information by tweaking or hacking but am wondering if there is a better export tool for this?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of output you want, could you clarify?  What would you like to see? Are you trying to display the whole database (similar to Family Historian's Everyone diagram)?